# Trying to connect to MongoDB using Realm

Tags: javascript, typescript, mongodb, realm, mobx-state-tree

It's the first time I use Realm and MongoDB.
I followed this [good tutorial](https://blog.shahednasser.com/how-to-integrate-mongo-realm-with-react-part-1/) as starting point and I create this project.

https://codesandbox.io/s/realm-forked-mrjex?file=/src/state/DbModel.ts

The folder structure is:

```js
src
|_ components
   |_ pages
      |_ Authentication.tsx
      |_ Home.tsx
      |_ Logout.tsx
   |_ App.tsx
   |_ Navigation.tsx
   |_ RestaurantCard.tsx
|_ lib
   |_ db-utils.ts
|_ state
   |_ index.ts
   |_ DbModel.ts
```

They are all very easy components, I post here only some pieces of them.

App.tsx:

```
const serviceName = "mongodb-atlas";

export function App() {
  return (
    <Provider value={stateInstance}>
      <AppWithState />
    </Provider>
  );
}

function AppWithState() {
  const {
    db: { app, client, setClient, user, setUser }
  } = useMst();

  useEffect(() => {
    async function init() {
      if (!user) {
        const credentials = Realm.Credentials.anonymous();
        const newUser = app.currentUser
          ? app.currentUser
          : await app.logIn(credentials);
        setUser(newUser);
      }
      if (!client) {
        const newClient = app.currentUser.mongoClient(serviceName);
        setClient(newClient);
      }
    }
    init();
  }, [app, client, user]);

  return (
    <Router>
      <Navigation />
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" component={Home} />
        ...
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

state/index.ts:

```
export const StateModel = t
  .model("StateModel", {
    db: t.optional(DbModel, {} as DbModelInstance)
  })
  .views((self) => ({}))
  .actions((self) => ({}));

export const stateInstance = StateModel.create();
export interface StateInstance extends Instance<typeof StateModel> {}

const RootStateContext = createContext<StateInstance | null>(null);
export const Provider = RootStateContext.Provider;

export function useMst() {
  const state = useContext(RootStateContext);
  if (state === null)
    throw new Error("State cannot be null, please add a context provider");
  return state;
}
```

state/DbModel.ts:

```
const appId = process.env.REACT_APP_REALM_APP_ID;
const appConfig: Realm.AppConfiguration = {
  id: appId
};
const app: Realm.App = new Realm.App(appConfig);

export const DbModel = t
  .model("DbModel", {
    app: t.optional(t.frozen<Realm.App>(), app),
    user: t.optional(t.frozen<Realm.User>(), null),
    client: t.optional(t.frozen<any>(), null)
  })
  .views((self) => ({
    get root() {
      return getRoot(self) as any;
    }
  }))
  .views((self) => ({}))
  .actions((self) => ({
    setApp(app: Realm.App) {
      self.app = app;
    },

    setUser(user: Realm.User) {
      self.user = user;
    },

    setClient(client: any) {
      self.client = client;
    }
  }))
  .actions((self) => ({}));

export interface DbModelInstance extends Instance<typeof DbModel> {}
```

Home.tsx:

```
export function Home() {
  const {
    db: { user, client }
  } = useMst();

  const [restaurants, setRestaurants] = useState([]);
  const isLoading = restaurants.length === 0;

  useEffect(() => {
    async function getData() {
      if (!client || !user) return;
      const rests = client.db("sample_restaurants").collection("restaurants");
      setRestaurants(await rests.find());
    }

    getData();
  }, [isLoading, client, user]);

  if (isLoading) {
    return <div>HOME Loading...</div>;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {restaurants.map((restaurant) => (
        <RestaurantCard key={restaurant._id} restaurant={restaurant} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Authentication.tsx:

```
const userSchema = yup.object().shape({
  email: yup.string().email().required(),
  password: yup.string().required().min(8)
});

export function Authentication({ type = "login" }) {
  const {
    db: { app, user, setUser, client }
  } = useMst();

  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const history = useHistory();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isAnon(user)) {
      history.push("/");
    }
  }, [history, user]);

  async function submitHandler(values: any) {
    setIsLoading(true);
    if (type === "create") {
      // @ts-ignore
      await app.emailPasswordAuth.registerUser(values.email, values.password);
    }
    // login user and redirect to home
    const credentials = Realm.Credentials.emailPassword(
      values.email,
      values.password
    );
    // @ts-ignore
    setUser(await app.logIn(credentials));
    setIsLoading(false);
  }

  return (
    <Formik
      initialValues={{
        email: "",
        password: ""
      }}
      validationSchema={userSchema}
      onSubmit={submitHandler}
    >
      {({ errors, touched, handleSubmit, values, handleChange }) => (
        <Form noValidate onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          {isLoading && <div className="">AUTH Loading...</div>}

          <div>
            <h1>{type === "login" ? "Login" : "Sign Up"}</h1>
            <Form.Row>
              <Form.Label>Email</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control
                type="email"
                name="email"
                value={values.email}
                onChange={handleChange}
                isValid={touched.email && !errors.email}
              />
              <Form.Control.Feedback>{errors.email}</Form.Control.Feedback>
            </Form.Row>
            <Form.Row>
              <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control
                type="password"
                name="password"
                value={values.password}
                onChange={handleChange}
                isValid={touched.password && !errors.password}
              />
              <Form.Control.Feedback>{errors.password}</Form.Control.Feedback>
            </Form.Row>

            <div className="text-center mt-2">
              <Button variant="primary" type="submit">
                Submit
              </Button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </Form>
      )}
    </Formik>
  );
}

function isAnon(user: Realm.User) {
  return !user || user.identities[0].providerType === "anon-user";
}
```

Basically I used a sample DB of restaurants.
In the tutorial, the author use the React context to save Db info like app, user and client but I prefer to setup a Mobx state tree. I think this is the only difference.
Oh, and I use TypeScript (btw, what is the type of `client`? I didn't understand reading the guide, it seems MongoDB but from where need I to import it?).

My code doesn't work.
I get nothing, still loading:

[image]

My app I think is stuck in `Home` component, in the `getData()` function because both `client` and `user` are `null`, but in `App` I created them and saved in my state so I don't understand what's going wrong..

**EDIT**: and sometimes, as Danila noted, I get also this error `Cannot assign to read only property '_locationUrl' of object '#<App>'`.

I cloned the repo created by the author, it works. What's wrong with my code? I think is a problem of a Promise but I'm not sure and I don't know how to solve :(

Comment: While loading your example I instantly have an error `Cannot assign to read only property '_locationUrl' of object '#<App>'`. Is that what you trying to solve?

Comment: @Danila Also. I don't understand what that problem means

Comment: It’s a good idea to include code, errors and and structures as *text*, not links and images. That way, if they are needed in an answer, they can be copied and pasted. Also, if the links break, it would invalidate the question. See [images and links are evil](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). Images are not searchable which may prevent future readers from locating the question. Also, take a look at [No Images Please](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). The question is unclear as well, can you clarify it?

Comment: @Jay you are right, for that reason I created the codesandbox. it includes the entire code, except the app id (for obvious reasons I think). I thought it was the best solution to make the question clear. I added also the screenshot to prove that in local the app runs but it breaks after a while

Comment: So what if, in a year, the code sandbox link changes? Then how will users know what the question is? Like right now; I clicked on the link and all I get is "Loading Sandbox" nothing more. I'm just trying to help you get an answer so it's best to follow the guidelines of [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to increase the chances you will get help. Followed by [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Jay, I edited my question. I hope now is good. I add some code pieces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `mobx-state-tree` with [`types.frozen`](https://mobx-state-tree.js.org/API/#frozen) in `DbModel.ts`.
That is messing with `Realm.App` because internally MongoDB Realm code is trying to alter the `Realm.App` instance but it will fail since you have that instance frozen.

Moving the `Realm.App` creation in your App code should fix the issue. Something like:

```
function AppWithState() {
  const {
    db: {   client, setClient, user, setUser }
  } = useMst();
  const [app] = useState(new Realm.App(appConfig)) // <-- here is the fix, along with deleting the Realm.App instantiation code from DbModel.ts
 
  .... rest of your AppWithState code .....
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried but now there are two problems:

1. other components need `app`, so I move the app creation in AppWithState as you suggested me but then I need also to move `app` inside db model, so I think to add `setApp(app)` (mobx action) in the `useEffect` of `AppWithState`. What do you think about it?
2. Always the old problem **Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property '_locationUrl' of object '#<App>'**

Comment: Both you issues are caused by the `Realm.App` being used with `mobx-state-tree`. You must move that out of  the `DbModel`  - same goes for all `Realm` references (ex: Realm.User being immutable means it will fail to refresh the authentication token).  Just use regular react `useContext` code for that. You can then access it via `const app = useContext(AppContext);` in other places